How do I install Discord using apt on Debian/Ubuntu?
I would like to update Discord on Debian/Ubuntu with a simple command, without having to go to their website and download the .deb file.
I have tried searching for a working apt repo, but the only one I found (on Reddit) was http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/ which doesn't seem to work any more:
echo "deb http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}'/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/discord.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install discord

This gives me the error:
Ign:3 http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/lsb_release -c InRelease

Err:3 http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/lsb_release -c InRelease

Could not resolve 'packages.discordapp.net'

How do I update Discord by running a command in the terminal?
Preferably, I'd like to add an apt repo so that it updates when I run apt upgrade or apt dist-upgrade but I understand that one might not be available.
Edit: Thanks to Daniel B's comment, I see that the original command was copy/pasted in correctly. Here is the corrected version:
echo "deb http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/$(lsb_release -c | awk '{print $2}')/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/discord.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install discord

However, this gives me the error:
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.discordapp.net/repo/bookworm/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'packages.discordapp.net'

At first, I thought they simply didn't have a Debian release, but then I noticed that the domain packages.discordapp.net isn't even resolvable.
$ nslookup packages.discordapp.net
Server:     100.100.100.100
Address:    100.100.100.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find packages.discordapp.net: No answer


Your script snippet isn't correct in the first place. lsb_release is a command to be called, piping its output to awk.

Oh wow! How did I miss that? Thanks. I copy-pasted from a Reddit thread and it looks like the formatting confused me: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/127kic5/comment/jefocmg/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

Ah, damn, domain is still invalid: packages.discordapp.net

The reddit comment is AI garbage or something, Discord has never provided official repos for this stuff, the debs are all we have.

Agreed, the Reddit comment very much seems like an AI hallucination.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a repo available at the moment (hopefully this will change).
One solution (not the best) is to make a script, ~/Scripts/update-discord.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

url="https://discord.com/api/download?platform=linux&format=deb"
curl -L -o /tmp/discord.deb $url
sudo apt install /tmp/discord.deb

Then make the script executable:
chmod +x ~/Scripts/update-discord.sh

Run the new script to update Discord:
~/Scripts/update-discord.sh

Optionally, you can also create a link to the script:
ln -s ~/Scripts/update-discord.sh ~/.local/bin/update-discord
source ~/.profile

Then you can run update-discord from anywhere.
